# speed up array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following formula which I will explain below:

```
{=SUM(IF(($G$1:$L$1=$O$1)*($G$2:$L$2=$O$2)*($G$3:$L$3=$O$3)*($G$4:$L$4=$O$4)*($G$5:$L$5=$O$5)*($G$6:$L$6=$O$6)*($G$7:$L$7=$O$7);G21:L21))}
```

Here is what the worksheet looks like:

[image]

Under columns **G - L** we have a 'database' of all data. These columns will be added cumulatively each quarter (approx 30 columns a quarter). So after a few years we have ended up with a bunch of database columns (1000 + columns of raw data). For the sake of this demo, I have only included those 6 columns.

As you can see, each column contains specific parameters, between rows **1 - 7**, which allows to identify specific CountryCode + Project Code + Category + Fiscal Year, + ... (etc.). This allows us to track down a unique specific project and retrieve its data.

What we have afterwards on the column **O** is a specific project we are trying to retrieve values for (you can see that the rows **1 - 7** are the same as under column **G** (we are trying to retrieve values for this particular project).

[image]

Here comes our formula. I have attached above. Here is what it looks like when I press **F2**. As you can see the **IF** statement is first simply checking whether the particular columns match the pre-defined criteria under column **O** and it sums all the columns that match all the criteria between rows **1-7**.

Now here is the problem. We have a worksheet, which contains 20 projects (such as column O) and we are using this array formula there to retrieve values. The problem is that retrieving data using this way takes A LOT OF TIME. We have also adopted a principle via VBA that we iterate through all the cells, then we insert a formula, calculate array cell, and then we copy & Paste resulting value inside (so that we won't end up with full sheet of array formulas). However it still takes LONG to calculate (1 minute or so).

I was wondering, if there is a better solution how to retrieve the data in the already mentioned format (that means we have a specific criteria we are trying to find)? Maybe SUMIFS could be better? Or sumproduct? Or even compeltely different solution?

I am open to any proposal which would fasten the process.

Comment: How many rows in O column contain this formula?

Comment: have you tied the standard SUMIFS(); `=SUMIFS(G21:L21;$G$1:$L$1;$O$1,$G$2:$L$2;$O$2;$G$3:$L$3;$O$3;$G$4:$L$4;$O$4;$G$5:$L$5;$O$5;$G$6:$L$6;$O$6;$G$7:$L$7;$O$7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i met similar problem about 2 weeks ago. At first i use a helper column/row. The helper column is to concatenate the 7 string in each column. then only use the IF function to check if the joined text match. Such as, assuming the helper row is row 8 per your sample, cell G8 formula would be

```
=CONCATENATE(G1,"|",G2,"|",G3,"|",G4,"|",G5,"|",G6,"|",G7)
```

and do the same for the rest including column O

```
=CONCATENATE(O1,"|",O2,"|",O3,"|",O4,"|",O5,"|",O6,"|",O7)
```

Then do a HLOOKUP

```
=HLOOKUP(O8,G8:L21,14,0)
```

In my case, the calculation time reduce from 10 min to a few seconds!

Alternatively I also found a way to do without helper column, using array again, but the idea is pretty much the same,

the formula in O21 as per your sample would be

```
=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(G1:L1,G2:L2,G3:L3,G4:L4,G5:L5,G6:L6,G7:L7)=CONCATENATE(O1,O2,O3,O4,O5,O6,O7),G21:L21))
```

(i didn't add in the "|" delimiter for this formula, but it is better to do so)

But in the end I prefer the helper column method.

For your reference

[image]

HTH

Comment: Will definitely give this a try and will let you know how the speed test went!

Comment: performance increased from 17~25 seconds to less than 10 seconds. Thank you

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance avoid reapeating same calculations multiple times.

> This allows us to track down a unique specific project and retrieve its data.

If a combination of 7 values is unique, calculate the position of chosen project only once in helper cell (for example `O15`) with array formula (confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=MATCH(1;(G1:L1=O1)*(G2:L2=O2)*(G3:L3=O3)*(G4:L4=O4)*(G5:L5=O5)*(G6:L6=O6)*(G7:L7=O7);0)
```

Use the following formula in `O21` and drag down:

```
=INDEX(G21:L21;1;$O$15)
```